# Using jpackage how do I make the installer name different than application name?

Tags: installation, exe, jpackage, application-name

I have a Java program that I can turn into an installer exe that makes an app exe

```
jpackage -t exe -i . -n compilerrunner --app-version 1.0 --win-dir-chooser --win-shortcut --main-jar compilerrunner.jar
```

I want the installer exe, to look like `compilerrunner-installer-1.0.exe` and the actual application to look like `compilerrunner-1.0.exe`, reading through jpackage I don't see a way to do that nor examples of others doing this. Currently my installer and my app have the same name `compilerrunner-installer-1.0.exe`.

I don't want an alternative to jpackage, I know there are other ways, I am **only** looking for ways to do this with jpackage.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to your problem is to use "--add-launcher" flag. You can read about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/packaging-tool-user-guide.pdf (page 18 - add launchers). You'll need to provide a .properties files which can be empty I believe. To specify the exe name, use --add-launcher like this:

```
--add-launcher NAME_OF_EXE=file.properties
```

where file.properties is some file of yours that can be empty. jpackage will create a exe named NAME_OF_EXE.exe executable file.

Answer (score 0):

JPackage only creates installers for Windows environments. Be aware that it creates Debian packages on Linux and DMG bundles on MacOS. In those cases it is absolutely fine to have the package name being the same as the application name, however they carry a different extension.

Since i do not believe JPackage offers any command line option to distinguish package name vs application name, simply renaming the installer as soon as JPackage is finished might be the most straightforward way to go.

Edit: would it still be ok to generate an MSI? Then the names would also differ by extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `--add-launcher` flag and specify a file with the arguments to create another launcher with a different name.